# How to add Authenticated cloud function behind GCP api gateway having firebase auth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-api-gateway

My setup is like

API lib built on top of API gateway endpoints => gateway authenticates requests against firebase users => Call Cloud function for an endpoints.

This seems to be working fine.

Only concern is security/authentication of cloud function.
How to achieve.

1. No one should be able to call cloud function directly
2. OR Cloud function should accept traffic only from API gateway.

Current settings are :

[image]

[image]

If i change allow internal traffic only then API gives a Not allowed error.

Answer (score 1):

Partial ans is here:
I figured out that i was not setting correct jwt_audience thats where it was throwing "Your client does not have permission to the requested URL": 401.

because my function URL was not same as what i mentioned in OpenApi spec. I had postfix to my URL, hence my request were failing.

earlier :

```
    options:
      x-google-backend:
         address: https://**-**-**-test.cloudfunctions.net/<funtion_name>/filter
```

Now:

```
    options:
       x-google-backend:
         address: https://*-**-**-test.cloudfunctions.net/<funtion_name>/filter
         jwt_audience: https://**-**-**-test.cloudfunctions.net/<funtion_name>
```

I tried to set setting "allow internal traffic only" but its failing with 403. Still i am not sure if i can set internal only traffic for cloud function along with API gateway.